# Python-Godot: _input causes game to stop running

Tags: crash, game-engine, godot

I was making a camera for my character when the game began to close its self. I realized that it was only occurring when I moved my mouse. It would say (before I moved my mouse):

```
--- Debugging process started ---
Godot Engine v3.2.2.stable.official - https://godotengine.org
OpenGL ES 3.0 Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
 
Pythonscript 0.40.0 (CPython 3.8.3.final.0)
Calling wrapper on <class 'scripts.Player.Player'>
Calling wrapper on <class 'scripts.main.main'>
Calling wrapper on <class 'scripts.test1.test1'>
```

and when I moved my mouse it would add:
`--- Debugging process stopped ---`

It works with gdscript, but breaks with python. This is all that is needed for this to happen:

```py
def _input(self,event):
    pass
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I only see one reference to `_input` in the godot-python repo, but it is commented out with a note that says "segfaults". The input method may not be supported yet. Try polling `Input` in `_process`.

Comment: How would I get InputEventMouseMotion in _process?

Comment: I don't think the self parameter should be added unless you're using the function in a class